# Calculate flow integral using Stokes's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Calculate the flow integral $$\iint_{Y} \text{curl} (\vec{F}) · \hat{N} dS$$
where $Y$ is part of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + (z − 2)^2 = 8$ that lies
above the $xy$-plane and $\hat{N}$ is the outward unit normal vector on $Y$
and $$F(x, y , z) = (y^2 \cos(xz), x^3e^{yz} , −e^{−xyz}).$$

[image]

I got the answer $48\pi$ but the correct answer is $12\pi$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you doing what your title said?

Comment: @TedShifrin I used curl in my calculation Ig

Comment: That’s *not* applying Stokes’s Theorem; that’s direct evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your work it seems that you are evaluating the flux of the curl of $\mathbf{F}$ through the disc $S$ (upward oriented) at the bottom of the truncated sphere $Y$:
$$\begin{align}
S&=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2\leq 8, z=0\}\\
&=\{(x,y,0): x^2+y^2\leq 8-(0-2)^2=4\}.
\end{align}$$
That's fine because $S$ and $Y$ [have the same boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807114/stokes-theorem-orientation) (with the same induced orientation).
However the radius of such disc is $2$ (not $\sqrt{8}$), therefore, the final integral should be
$$\pi\int_0^23r^3\,dr=\pi\left[\frac{3r^4}{4}\right]_0^2=12\pi.$$

The same result can be obtained by applying [Stokes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) in a more direct way:
$$\begin{align}
\iint_{Y} &\text{curl} (\mathbf{F})\cdot\mathbf{n}\, dS=
\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} ((2\sin(t))^2 \cos(0), (2\cos(t))^3e^{0} , −e^{0})\cdot(-2\sin(t),2\cos(t),0)dt\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}(-8\sin^3(t)+16\cos^4(t)) dt=0+ 16\cdot \frac{3\pi}{4}=12\pi
\end{align}$$
where $\gamma$ is the boundary of $Y$ (and $S$) counterclockwise oriented, that is the circle
$$\gamma(t)=(2\cos(t),2\sin(t),0)\quad\text{ with $t\in [0,2\pi]$}.$$

Comment: Wait isn't this like a sphere? Why is the radius $\sqrt{8- (0-2)^2}$. Isn't my solution a stokes theorem?

Comment: In your work you parametrized a disk not a part of sphere (the normal vector  $(0,0,r)$ is vertical). Such disk is the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2\leq 8$ and the plane $z=0$.

Comment: For a direct evaluation through $Y$ the parametrization should be different. Using **spherical** coordinates the limits for $r$ would be $0$ and $\sqrt{8}$

Comment: Also how was your second suggestion related to Stoke's theorem? You didn't take the curl and shouldn't you be using double integral? I am confused right now.

Comment: when you said I parametrized a wrong disc is it because we are interested in the disc at the xy-plane where z=0? Which means we are then left with $x^2+y^2 + (0-2)^2 = 8 \iff x^2+y^2 = 4$ and this gives me the radius 2? If I understood correctly then I've one more thing to ask. So far I have been using Stoke's theorem on closed lines in 3D so if I am asked to analyse a surface like a hemisphere, I am supposed to focus on the edge line right and not on the surface itself?

Comment: The definition (only definition) I have learned about Stoke's theorem is: $\int_{\gamma}\vec{F} · dr =\iint_{Y} \nabla \times \vec{F} · \hat{N} dS$.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I edited my answer. Any further doubt?

Comment: Could you confirm to me that when given a surface for example hemisphere like in this case I should only focus on the edge (of course when it comes to flux integral) right? Aside from that: how does the double integral equal to this $\int_{γ}F⋅ds$, my guess is because you didn't take r as a variable but then what happend to Curl(F)?When it comes dS, you used the gradient for the level curve to get the normal right? And last but not least why didn't you use "r" as a variable? Sorry for asking multiple questions but I am just making sure I understand everything correctly?

Comment: 1) I confirm 2) surface integral of curl(F)=line integral of F is just the statement of Stokes integral, 3) yes, 4) I think you should review line integrals

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it!